# Drawing the letter "M" in the console using C#

Tags: c#, console

I'm having troulbe with drawing the letter M in the console using "*" for the letter and  using "-" as empty space.

The thickness of the letter is read from the console.

Where - n is a positive integer and always an odd number 2< n < 10000

So far I haven't come up with anything resembling a solution.

```
int  n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = n+1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("-");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Example:Here is how the letter should look if  n = 5 :

[image]

Edit: I appologise for the poorly writen question its my first time asking here. :(

Comment: please add a [mcve] of what you want to achieve.. I understand what it should do, but i dont get what the input does. Is this for some kind of homework?

Comment: I guess, `n` is to be the number of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the .Net Fiddle link below, this is a general solution for any letter or letters, I forked it to work with letters as the original author designed it to work with images, try with the variables M, 100

https://dotnetfiddle.net/DEY9il

output would be somthing like the below:-

```
Enter the letter?M
Enter Line Character Amount100

 ###################################################################################################
 ###################################################################################################
 ###################################################################################################
 ####  .#######*  ##################################################################################
 ####   @######   ##################################################################################
 ####   .#####* . ##################################################################################
 ####  + %#### +  ##################################################################################
 ####  # -###+ #  ##################################################################################
 ####  #: ### :#  ##################################################################################
 ####  ## .#w ##. ##################################################################################
 ####  ##: @ *##. ##################################################################################
 ####  ##@ , @##  ##################################################################################
 ####  ###, ,###. ##################################################################################
 ###################################################################################################
 ###################################################################################################
 ###################################################################################################
 ###################################################################################################
 ###################################################################################################
```

you can tweak it to print only the characters you want.

There is a million ways to do this, but this is another was that uses functions, by breaking M to four lines, and drawing for that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;                   
public class Program
{
    static List<List<string>> board;
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Width:");
        var width=ReadWidth();
        var emptyText="-";
        var fillText="*";

        board=new List<List<string>>();

        //for M we will use 4 points each with a width of [width]
        Func<int,int,bool> p1=(row,col)=>{ 
                        int startX=width-1-row;
                        return (col>startX && col<=(startX+width));
                    };
        Func<int,int,bool> p2=(row,col)=>{ 
                        int startX=width-1+row;
                        return (col>startX && col<=(startX+width));
                    };
        Func<int,int,bool> p3=(row,col)=>{ 
                        int startX=(3*width)-1-row;
                        return (col>startX && col<=(startX+width));
                    };
        Func<int,int,bool> p4=(row,col)=>{ 
                        int startX=(3*width)-1+row;
                        return (col>startX && col<=(startX+width));
                    };



        for(int row=0;row<=width;row++)
        {
            var rowChars=new List<string>();
            for(int col=0;col<(width*5);col++)
                rowChars.Add((p1(row,col) || p2(row,col) || p3(row,col) || p4(row,col))?fillText:emptyText);
            board.Add(rowChars);
        }
        ShowOutput();
    }
    public static int ReadWidth()
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Width (odd number beteween 2< Input < 1000):");
        var widthString=Console.ReadLine();
        int width=0;
        if(!int.TryParse(widthString,out width) || width<2 || width >1000)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("The value entered is not accepted, please try again.");
            ReadWidth();
        }
        return width;
    }
    public static void ShowOutput()
    {
        var sb=new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach(List<string> row in board)
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join("",row.ToArray()));

        Console.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

for Input of 10, the output is as below:-

```
Enter Width:
Enter Width (odd number beteween 2< Input < 1000):
10
----------**********----------**********----------
---------************--------************---------
--------**************------**************--------
-------****************----****************-------
------******************--******************------
-----****************************************-----
----**********--******************--**********----
---**********----****************----**********---
--**********------**************------**********--
-**********--------************--------**********-
**********----------**********----------**********
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to draw four lines. Each line is a function that looks like `x=y*A+B`. `x` and `y` swapped places here to make more sense. You write row by row, incrementing `y` in the process, and for each `y` you cycle through `x`, and for each `x` you should determine if it conforms to at least one condition that places `(x,y)` inside one of four lines. Condition for each line is that `x` is greater or equal `y*A+B` and smaller or equal `y*A+B+N`, where `N` is the thickness. In this particular case `A` will be either 1 or -1. If `(x,y)` satisfies at least one of four condition then write `'*'`, otherwise write `'-'`. You have to figure out the values of `A` and `B` for each of four lines. You must also figure out the range of the `x` loop (it has to end at certain point, when you should move on to another row).